# boost daytime7 server example doesn't respond to netcat client

Tags: c++, boost, server, boost-asio

I am trying to get the daytime6 server example (Asynchronous UDP daytime  server) in boost working. I compile the below program using

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -pedantic udp_server.cpp -o udp_server -lboost_system
```

I start the `udp_server`. I can see port number 13 (UDP) being opened using netstat command.

However If I trying to client to the server using netcat

```
nc -u localhost 13
```

it doesn't seem to give any reply.However I can get the asynchronous TCP daytime server to work fine.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

std::string make_daytime_string()
{
  using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
  time_t now = time(0);
  return ctime(&now);
}

class udp_server
{
public:
  udp_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 13))
  {
    start_receive();
  }

private:
  void start_receive()
  {
    socket_.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer_), remote_endpoint_,
        boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_receive, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
  {
    if (!error || error == boost::asio::error::message_size)
    {
      boost::shared_ptr<std::string> message(
          new std::string(make_daytime_string()));

      socket_.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(*message), remote_endpoint_,
          boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_send, this, message,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

      start_receive();
    }
  }

  void handle_send(boost::shared_ptr<std::string> message,
      const boost::system::error_code& error,
      std::size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
  }

  udp::socket socket_;
  udp::endpoint remote_endpoint_;
  boost::array<char, 1> recv_buffer_;
};

int main()
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    udp_server server(io_service);
    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sending the UDP daytime server any messages to which it can respond?  Do you see the expected response with something like `echo 'msg' | nc -u localhost 13`?

Comment: @TannerSansbury - why is that required? also would any message buffer do?

Comment: @TannerSansbury - why does only UDP server need it and TCP  server doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command does not send a message:

```
$ nc -u localhost 13
```

Instead, netcat will wait, reading from stdin until end-of-file.  Upon receiving end-of-file, it will send the message it reads to localhost on port 13 using UDP.

On the other hand, the following command:

```
$ echo 'msg' | nc -u localhost 13
```

writes "msg" and end-of-file to netcat's stdin, resulting in netcat sending a UDP datagram containing "msg" to localhost on port 13.

The [asynchronous UDP daytime server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime6/src.html) example responds to any message it receives with the current date and time:

```cpp
class udp_server
{
public:
  udp_server(...)
  {
    start_receive();
  }

private:
  void start_receive()
  {
    socket_.async_receive_from(...,
        boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_receive, ...));
  }

  void handle_receive(...)
  {
    message = make_daytime_string();

    socket_.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(message), ...);
  }

};
```

As the first command does not write a message, the `udp_server` never receives a message to which it can respond.  The latter command causes a message to be written, and the `udp_server` responds with the date and time.

The [asynchronous TCP daytime server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html) writes a message upon accepting a connection, then closes the connection.  When using TCP, netcat will attempt to connect to the destination immediately.  In the case of the `tcp_server`, netcat will establish a TCP connection, receive the date and time, detect that the remote peer has closed the connection and exit.